# Keep borderless window open when clicking chrome on second screen

Tags: google-chrome, window

I have a 2 screen setup with Ubuntu 18.04 installed.

When I play CSGO on fullscreen windowed and I have Google opened on my other screen and I want to browse Google when I die in CSGO. But when I click on Chrome, my CSGO alt tabs away like in Windows 10, but I want this to still be open.

How do I do this? Is this possible?

Comment: I'm almost sure it isn't possible.

Comment: What is "fullscreen windowed"?

Comment: @danzel it is the same as borderless but for normal tasks as mozilla or firefox you don't use it is is mostly usen in games